# Dimensions.get('screen') not working in React Native

Tags: react-native

Im using react-native dimensions to get dimensions of screen and determine if user is in portrait or landscape mode.....however `Dimensions.get('screen').height` is ALWAYS coming back as the longer of the 2 sides, even when in landscape mode.....i.e. `Dimensions.get('screen').height` is always coming back as larger than `Dimensions.get('screen').width`, even when in landscape mode

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      orientation: (Dimensions.get('screen').height >= Dimensions.get('screen').width ? 'portrait' : 'landscape')
    };

    Dimensions.addEventListener('change', () => {
      let orientation = (Dimensions.get('screen').height >= Dimensions.get('screen').width ? 'portrait' : 'landscape');
      this.setState({
        orientation: orientation
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [useWindowDimensions()](https://reactnative.dev/docs/usewindowdimensions).
Just put something like this in your root component :

```
const SCREEN_WIDTH = useWindowDimensions().width;
const SCREEN_HEIGHT = useWindowDimensions().height;
return (
    <View style={{ width: SCREEN_WIDTH, minHeight: SCREEN_HEIGHT}} >
        //the rest of your app
    </View>
);
```

Comment: Cant call hooks from a class component....Id need to rewrite my entire app.  Is there no other way to make Dimensions work?

Comment: You could always wrap the component which needs these values with a functional component, use the hooks there to get the values, and then pass those values into the class component which needs them as props. Regardless, though, I don't know that this hook will solve your problem. I'm having the same issue, and I used the hook after my original code didn't work. It didn't fix the issue for me.